# How to save a record into SQL Server using specifc constraint?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL server 2008 with C#. For instance temporary type ticket can be registered with one or more Employee ID. But I want to register permanent type ticket only ones per employee.

The following table shows that the 2nd record is registered incorrectly. So how can I handle such constraints?

```
+-------+--------+----------+-----------+
| empid | userid | ticketNo | ticketType|
+-------+--------+----------+-----------+
|    1  | admin  |       10 | Permanent |
|    1  | admin  |       11 | Permanent |
|     2 | admin  |       12 | Temporary |
+-------+--------+----------+-----------+
```

I have tried the following but not work as needed.

```
private void CheckandBlockEmp()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dbcon.ReturnConnection());

    string commText = "select EmpID from ItemTicketSection where ticketType='Permanent'";
    SqlCommand cmdCheck = new SqlCommand(commText, conn);

    conn.Open();

    var check = cmdCheck.ExecuteScalar();

    if (check != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Permanent type ticket is allowed only ones per Employee!");
        return;
    }
}
```

For example valid TicketNo registration table:

```
+-------+--------+----------+-----------+
| empid | userid | ticketNo |ticketType |
+-------+--------+----------+-----------+
|    1  | admin  |       10 | Permanent |
|     2 | admin  |       12 | Temporary |
|     2 | admin  |       13 | Permanent |
|     1 | admin  |       14 | Temporary |
+-------+--------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Your column name is `Type` not `ticketType`. You should change your query as `select EmpID from ItemTicketSection where Type = 'Permanent'`.

Comment: In your sql code, create a scalar function and then use it in a check constraint to restrict multiple input during the insert operation. This has nothing to do with C#. It can be done purely in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution will be filtered unique index. It will deny duplicate emps for `Permanent` type only:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Indexname] ON ItemTicketSection 
(
    [empid] ASC
)
WHERE ([Type]=('Permanent'))
```

Comment: the issue is solved. Can you tell me what it does internally?

Comment: Can I add my own Exception to the above UNIQUE INDEX, when the event is fired?

Comment: As I have said in answer this is the index on empid column that will force uniqueness on empid column when type = Permanent. And yes, you can further edit that predicate. For example WHERE ([Type]=('Permanent') and userid <> 'Admin') - admin can add duplicate permanent types, others can not do this.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to CHECK if you have an EmpID with a Permanent ticket already registered then you could change your method to

```
private bool CheckandBlockEmp(int empID)
{
    string commText = @"IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ItemTicketSection 
                                   WHERE [Type]='Permanent' AND EmpID=@id) 
                                   SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0";
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dbcon.ReturnConnection()))
    using(SqlCommand cmdCheck = new SqlCommand(commText, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmdCheck.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = empID;
        var check = cmdCheck.ExecuteScalar();
        if (check != null)
        {
            int num = Convert.ToInt32(check);
            return (num == 0);
        }
        else
            return true;
    } 
}
```

I have changed a bit of your logic. Now the method returns 0 if the EmpID passed to the method has zero 'Permanent' Ticket registered otherwise it returns 1.
In this way is the calling code that decides if it is safe to register a record with the Permanent ticket flag for that particular EmpID

As other answer has said, adding an unique index will ensure the coherence of your business rule, but if you want to check and inform your user before attempting to save a record then you need code like this to verify your table

Comment: I'd say this method may have some performance problems, if you used a method that could break upon the first encounter of desired value, that would be much better. (Performance Wise)

Comment: Yes there are a lot of solutions for this scenario. You could use IF EXISTS for example